# Neptune Gremlin query to recommend users based on common AND positive rated content

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

The Gremlin query pasted below returns an ordered list of friends of a given user - the ordering is descending, based on "how many of the same movies have we rated". I would like to only compare those movies where rated.score > 5 (on a 10 point scale) the goal is to sort the results by "how many of the same movies have we rated positively". Thanks in advance!

```
  g.V('a2661f57-8aa7-4e5c-9c89-55cf9bxxxxx').as('self').
  sideEffect(out('rated').store('movies')). 
  out('friended').
  group(). 
    by(). 
    by(out('rated').where(within('movies')).count()). 
  order(local). 
    by(values,desc). 
    unfold().
  select(keys).
  project('id','label','username').
    by(id).
    by(label).
    by('username')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing some context of the "score".  Are you just using the count of ratings between common movies as the "score"?  Or is this a property on the 'rated' edge?

If so, you would just add a `where()` clause to your query to only return the results that are greater than 5.

`where(select(values).where(is(gt(5)))).`

```
g.V('a2661f57-8aa7-4e5c-9c89-55cf9bxxxxx').as('self').
  sideEffect(out('rated').store('movies')). 
  out('friended').
  group(). 
    by(). 
    by(out('rated').where(within('movies')).count()). 
  order(local). 
    by(values,desc). 
    unfold().
  where(select(values).where(is(gt(5)))).   //added filter
  select(keys).
  project('id','label','username').
    by(id).
    by(label).
    by('username')
```

If you wanted to filter on a ratings score that is included on a ratings edge, you would need to filter for this condition earlier in the query using:

`where(outE('rated').values('score').is(gt(5))).`

```
g.V('a2661f57-8aa7-4e5c-9c89-55cf9bxxxxx').as('self').
  sideEffect(out('rated').store('movies')). 
  out('friended').
  group(). 
    by(). 
    by(outE('rated')
            .where(values('score').is(gt(5)))  //filter on score
       .inV()
           .where(within('movies')).count()). 
  order(local). 
    by(values,desc). 
    unfold().
  select(keys).
  project('id','label','username').
    by(id).
    by(label).
    by('username')
```

Comment: is your example for the first case or the second case you were describing? score is an integer property in the rated edge. looks like the example is using the first case?

Comment: i would need to indicate the "score" property somewhere in the where condition, yes?

Comment: You would need to add the `score` filter into the by() statement for the group() step.  That would state that you're only counting the edges with a score > 5 and that are within the set of movies that the original user also rated.